# Check Hour Column For Existence Of All Hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that has a date column in the following format - "%mm/%dd/%yy %h:00". The column should have a row for each round hour of each day of the month, for example:

```
6/1/20 1:00
6/1/20 2:00
6/1/20 3:00
```

etc. But it's possible that I'll have more than one entry for each hour, like so:

```
6/1/20 1:00
6/1/20 1:00
6/1/20 1:00
6/1/20 2:00
6/1/20 3:00
6/1/20 3:00
...
6/2/20 0:00
```

How can I make sure that I have all the hours of the day (0:00,1:00,..,23:00) in the date column and I'm not missing some hour of the day?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking just a single day or each day of the month? Please can you include wanted result and own attempt to clear things up a little bit more. And also, what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: Checking each day of the month, the wanted results would be which hour is missing in which day.
Using Excel 16.36 for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Because is only 24 cases, you could use Excel Countif() function.
In a new sheet :

1. column A could contain the list of all "hours" you want to check (0:00,1:00,..,23:00)
2. column B the countif function where 1st argument is your data (listed above) and second one one of the hour you need to check.

Resulting :

- your first example (1:00, 2:00 and 3:00) = 1 each
- second one : 1:00 = 3, 2:00 = 1, 3:00 = 2 and 0:00 = 1
- where you get a 0 are the missing hours in your initial table